# Get only array elements with positive keys

Tags: php, arrays

How to filter out array elements with keys that are negative integers in PHP?

So if I have an array:

```
Array (
    [-3] => Academic degree
    [-4] => Academic discipline
    [-5] => African American history
    [-6] =>
    [1] => Art
)
```

the result would be: `Array ( [1] => Art )`.

My idea was to use something like this:

> $arr = array( '-1' => 1, '-2' => 2, '3' => 3,
>   'element4' => 4 ); $filterOutKeys = array( '-1', '-2' );
>
> $filteredArr = array_diff_key( $arr, array_flip( $filterOutKeys ) )

but it turned up as very impractical when dealing with bigger arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a simple foreach?

```
$filteredArr = array();
foreach($arr as $key => $value)
    if($key > 0)
        $filteredArr[$key] = $value;
```

Comment: "string keys" are not integers!? But you can just turn them into integers, using [`intval('-3g0-');`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php).

Answer (score 0):

Using [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) is another option:

```
$outputArray = array_filter($inputArray, function($value) {
    return ($value < 0) ? false : true;
});
```

EDIT: after seeing the comments, I must agree, that this does not what was wanted. But you may still use the flipped array:

```
$outputArray = array_flip(array_filter(array_flip($inputArray), function($value) {
    return ($value < 0) ? false : true;
}));
```

I don't know if this solution processes faster then the one stated by @Dani.

EDIT2: a complete test-case:

```
$inputArray = array(
    -3 => 'Academic degree',
    -4 => 'Academic discipline',
    -5 => 'African American history',
    1 => 'Art');

$outputArray = array_flip(array_filter(array_flip($inputArray), function($value) {
//  return ($value < 0) ? false : true;
    return $value > 0;
}));

var_dump($outputArray);

/* results in:

    array(1) {
      [1]=>
      string(3) "Art"
    }

 */
```

Comment: No. This function uses the values, not the keys.

Comment: You can change the return in the closure to `return $value > 0;` as that alone returns a boolean

Comment: always returns an empty array

Comment: @smihael No, only if there are only negative keys in the array. I've added a complete test-case to the answer…

Comment: Ah ups, I forgot to mention that I'm using multidimensional array, that's why it doesn't work. You can try with:
`$inputArray = array( -3 => 'aaa', -4 => array ("bbb", "ccc"), 1 => array("ddd", "eee"));`

Comment: @smihael That's why `array_flip` won't work, as array can't become keys…